# can not implicitly convert 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public bool InsertBank()
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERTBANKMASTER", dal.con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bank_Name",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Bank_Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bank_ShortName",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Bank_ShortName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreditCard_Commission_Percent",SqlDbType.Float).Value = CreditCard_Commission_Percent;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

i cannot resolve this error.. im new in c#.. so any body let me know how to correct it.

Comment: thank u gentle mans'..for ur answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code.

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
```

Comment: That only converts the implicit conversion to an explicit. The value doesn't represent a boolean in the first place, so it doesn't really make sense to convert it to one.

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery())` return false only `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is 0. otherwise it return true.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is supposed to return a value of type `bool`. But you return a value of type `int`, because `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of affected rows of your query as an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess:

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0;
```

But it depends on your query. Since this is a SPROC you might need to add a parameter with direction ReturnValur. Also note: your try/catch does nothing except destroy the .StackTrace and you should be "using" the SqlCommand.

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns an `int`, which you try to use as return value for the method.

If you want to check if at least one record was affected by the query:

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1;
```

If you want to check if exactly one record was affected by the query:

```
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your method `InsertBank()` declaration is not consistent with the value you are returning inside the method. Your method declaration says that it expect a bool `True` or `False` in return value but you are returning an `Integer` as `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns `int` not `bool`

You should think what you actually want in return from your method.